# temporarily disabling rails remote link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a toggle where I need to disable the remote link while the server sends the true/false data to the database. I will then re-enable the link on `ajax:success`.

I cant use `e.preventDefault()` on a rails remote link

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggle_link', function(){
  //disable remote link
})

$('body').on('ajax:success', '.toggle_link', function(){
  //enable remote link
})
```

Is there a best practice for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should disable remote link.

```
$('#remote_link').removeAttr('data-remote').removeAttr('href')
```

To re-enable it you can store target url in some `data` attribute (`data-target` or smth) and bring `href` back on `ajax:success`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also wire into the `ajax:beforeSend` event in ujs.

```
  $(document).on('ajax:beforeSend', 'a[data-remote=true]', function(event, xhr, status, error) {
    // stash the link
    // remove the href
  });
```

I used a varient of this to prevent data-remote links from running when they had a css class of 'disabled'

```
  $(document).on('ajax:beforeSend', 'a.disabled[data-remote=true]', function(event, xhr, status, error) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

What ended up working for me was using part of user2675613's answer and then also removing the `data-remote="true"` and `data-method="put"` attributes.

```
//to disable
var url_link = $(this).attr('href');
$(this).attr('data-href', url_link);
$(this).attr('href', "#");
$(this).removeAttr('data-remote');
$(this).removeAttr('data-method');

//to enable 
var url_link = $(this).attr('data-href');
$(this).attr("href", url_link);
$(this).attr("data-remote", "true");
$(this).attr("data-method", "put");
```

This was for a update action so depending on your action you could store the data-method.

Comment: why are you removing data-remote and data-method? It doesn't make sense, if your href is already `#` then why would you want to remove these two?

Comment: @user2675613 The link still ends up sending an empty request, I would rather completely disable the link.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the link on click you can `write it's jquery in your asset pipeline`. Since you can't use `e.preventDefault()`, why don't you simply `change it's href to #`. Use a data-href attribute which will contain your original link for re-enabling it again(incase you have lots of links and don't know which one will go where). So inside your jquery file you can do:

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggle_link', function(){
  $(this).prop("href", "#");
});
```

and to re-enable it again you can do:

```
$('body').on('ajax:success', '.toggle_link', function(){
  var url = $(this).data("href");
  $(this).prop("href",url);
});
```

In rails `js.erb` file is the ajax:success. So instead of writing the whole ajax:success code in your js you can write it in js.erb file, but you'll need to somehow send the value of data-href to your controller(incase you don't already know the url of link). You can do it by following these steps:

a. Make a `post` url in your routes.rb file to your custom action.

b. write your ajax call in your js file:

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggle_link', function(){
  var url_link = $(this).data("href");
  $(this).prop("href","#");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url_link,
    data: { data-url: url_link}
   });
});
```

c. Inside your custom action you can fetch that url by `@url = params[:data-url]`

d. Inside your js.erb file you can simple write

```
$("#some_id_of_link").prop("href",@url);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is being used to disable behavior of `remote: true` on `link_to` when adding the disabled attribute. Thus you can handle the situation in a cleaner way.

```
$('a[data-remote]').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if($(this).attr('disabled') == 'true' || $(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
    return false;
  }
});
```